# can't use SOIL in linux mint

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, soil

I am doing an assignment that requires me to use SOIL. I installed it using the command `sudo apt-get install libsoil-dev`, but when I try to compile my program, I get the following error:

```
textureMain.cpp:19:18: fatal error: SOIL.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
textureParams.cpp:17:18: fatal error: SOIL.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Why am I not able to compile the program even though I installed SOIL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ dpkg -L libsoil-dev |grep include
/usr/include
/usr/include/SOIL
/usr/include/SOIL/SOIL.h
/usr/include/SOIL/image_DXT.h
/usr/include/SOIL/image_helper.h
/usr/include/SOIL/stbi_DDS_aug.h
/usr/include/SOIL/stbi_DDS_aug_c.h
/usr/include/SOIL/stb_image_aug.h
```

So you probably want the following on the g++ command-line

```
-I /usr/include/SOIL
```

Or just use the following in your C++

```
#include <SOIL/SOIL.h>
```

And you probably want the following on the command-line when linking

```
-lSOIL
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add a -I compiler argument to tell it where to find the SOIL header files.

Comment: I'm not seeing it in my /usr/lib folder, and `find` is coming up blank. Where is it located?

Comment: The `-I` (include) option is for `*.h` headers, usually under `/usr/include/`